# How attach contentScript to frame?

Tags: javascript, firefox, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk

I use this code to attach my script into the tab.

```
tabs.activeTab.attach({
            contentScript: "alert('test');"
        });
    })
```

It works fine, but i want to attach my code into the IFRAME. How can I do it?

Comment: the page-mod module offers that functionality

Comment: It's true, but how i can attach script to one tab using page-mod?